# Oracle Pivot query gives columns with quotes around the column names. What?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I'm trying to use PIVOT in Oracle and I'm getting a weird result. It's probably just an option I need to set but what I know about Oracle/SQL I could fit into this comment box.

Here's an example of my query:

```
with testdata as
(
    select 'Fred' First_Name, 10 Items from dual
    union
    select 'John' First_Name, 5  Items from dual
    union 
    select 'Jane' First_Name, 12 Items from dual
    union
    select 'Fred' First_Name, 15 Items from dual
)

select * from testdata
pivot (
    sum(Items)
    for First_Name
    in ('Fred','John','Jane')
```

The results come out as I expected except the Column names have single quotes around them (picture from Toad - if I export to Excel the quotes get carried to Excel):

[image: Toad Data Grid]

How do I get rid of the single quotes around the column names? I tried taking them out in the "in" clause and I get an error:

```
in (Fred,John,Jane)
```

[image: Error message]

I also tried replacing the single quotes with double quotes and got the same error. I don't know if this is an Oracle option I need to set/unset before running my query or a Toad thing.

Comment: Might be a Toad issue rather than a SQL one.

Comment: You can provide column aliases inside your `IN`- see the [oracle docs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html)

Comment: My Duh. I've been reading the Oracle Pivot docs for two days and somehow I missed that. Thanks @bluefeet...

Answer (score 67, accepted):

you can provide aliases to the new columns in the `pivot` statement's `IN` clause. 
(NB: This is different from the standard where clause `IN()` which does not allow aliases.)

```sql
with testdata as
(
    select 'Fred' First_Name, 10 Items from dual
    union
    select 'John' First_Name, 5  Items from dual
    union 
    select 'Jane' First_Name, 12 Items from dual
    union
    select 'Fred' First_Name, 15 Items from dual
)
select * from testdata
pivot (
      sum(Items) 
      for First_Name
      in ('Fred' as fred,'John' as john,'Jane' as jane)
      )
```

and also for your aggregate clause which is necessary if you have multiple clauses..

```sql
with testdata as
(
    select 'Fred' First_Name, 10 Items from dual
    union
    select 'John' First_Name, 5  Items from dual
    union 
    select 'Jane' First_Name, 12 Items from dual
    union
    select 'Fred' First_Name, 15 Items from dual
)
select * from testdata
pivot (
    sum(Items) itmsum,
    count(Items) itmcnt
    for First_Name
    in ('Fred' as fred,'John' as john,'Jane' as jane)
   )
```

returns

```sql
FRED_ITMSUM FRED_ITMCNT JOHN_ITMSUM JOHN_ITMCNT JANE_ITMSUM JANE_ITMCNT
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
         25           2           5           1          12           1
```

Of course you can then go full circle and use standard oracle aliasing and rename them to whatever you like including putting quotes back in again..

```sql
with testdata as
(
    select 'Fred' First_Name, 10 Items from dual
    union
    select 'John' First_Name, 5  Items from dual
    union 
    select 'Jane' First_Name, 12 Items from dual
    union
    select 'Fred' First_Name, 15 Items from dual
)
select FRED_ITMSUM "Fred's Sum", FRED_ITMCNT "Fred's Count"
     , JOHN_ITMSUM "John's Sum", JOHN_ITMCNT "John's Count"
     , JANE_ITMSUM "Janes's Sum", JANE_ITMCNT "Janes's Count"
from testdata
pivot (
    sum(Items) itmsum,
    count(Items) itmcnt
    for First_Name
    in ('Fred' as fred,'John' as john,'Jane' as jane)
   )
```

gives

```sql
Fred's Sum Fred's Count John's Sum John's Count Janes's Sum Janes's Count
---------- ------------ ---------- ------------ ----------- -------------
        25            2          5            1          12             1
```