# How to categorize a data set without the use of `case when`

Tags: sql, oracle

Please have a look at my picture in which I have tried to explain what I want to achieve: each column should be the sum of values within the country and category. 
How will you suggest I solve this problem? There must be a standard approach by SQL user that I have overlooked.

I know I can work my way around it by something like

`case when category = 'CatA' then sum(value) as 'CatA'` and then a `group by`

but when my categories are too many this solution will be messy I will avoid it.

I am using Oracle SQL and Toad

**EDIT:**
I have two answers but I think I have mis communicated what I whish. Basically what I wish to achieve is to **avoid type in the categories manually**.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you are looking for a pivot table: https://stackoverflow.com/q/22103060/14955

Answer (score 0):

You want conditional aggregation.  The `case` is the argument to the `sum()`:

```
sum(case when category = 'CatA' then value end) as CatA
```

Also, don't use single quotes for column names -- this can leave to unexpected syntax errors and hard-to-debug run-time errors.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.

Comment: "but when my categories are too many this solution will be messy I will avoid it." (Not sure if there is a way around it though, you need to declare all the columns of the result after all, even in a pivot table)

Comment: @Thilo thank you! Gordon Linoff, I still have to declare each category seperatly so this does solve my problem. Thank you though.

Comment: @Thilo is it possible to do it in a loop or something like that? :)

Comment: @econmajorr . . . You can construct the query using a spreadsheet or another query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PIVOT` as following:

```
Select *
FROM (select country, category, value from your_table)
PIVOT
(sum(value) for 
  category in ('CatA', 'CatB', 'CatC', ....your other categories like this...)
);
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you very much Tejash. However, this will still require that I type in alle the categories manually. Is there anyway I can avoid that?