# aliasing pivot column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

i am trying to alias the pivot column to scenario1, scenario2, scenario3 instead of 1,2,3. I am getting error.

```
select *
from (select *
      from (select s.campaign_id campaign_id, s.scenario_index scenario_index 
            from scenario s, campaign c where s.campaign_id = c.campaign_id)
      pivot (max(scenario_index)for scenario_index in (1,2,3))
     )a
```

thank you, aggregation gives the result with alias now. The requirement i have is to combine these columns with another query which is

```
select  CASE WHEN AWARD_TYPE = 0 THEN award_rate||' points'
                                        when AWARD_TYPE = 1   then Award_rate||' %'
                                        when award_type=2  then RATIO_POINTS||' points per '||RATIO_MON_UNIT||' AED' End
                            from  points_rule p
                            where c.pt_basic_rule_id = p.point_rule_id ) as pool_awards,
```

this query comes as a column and then the scenario1, 2,3 should come as 3 columns with the value of the pool_award based on the campaign_id

Comment: Why are you choosing not to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Comment: You have several options to add aliases in pivot, described for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22103060/oracle-pivot-query-gives-columns-with-quotes-around-the-column-names-what).

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select s.campaign_id,
       max(case when scenario_index = 1 then 1 end) as scenario1,
       max(case when scenario_index = 2 then 1 end) as scenario2,
       max(case when scenario_index = 3 then 1 end) as scenario3
from scenario s join
     campaign c 
     on s.campaign_id = c.campaign_id
group by campaign_id;
```

Comment: thank you, it gives the same result with column alias, the requirement i have is to combine these columns with another query select  CASE WHEN AWARD_TYPE = 0 THEN award_rate||' points'
                                        when AWARD_TYPE = 1   then Award_rate||' %'
                                        when award_type=2  then RATIO_POINTS||' points per '||RATIO_MON_UNIT||' AED' End
                            from  points_rule p
                            where c.pt_basic_rule_id = p.point_rule_id ) as pool_awards

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alias in `IN` clause of the `PIVOT` as follows:

```
select *
from (select *
      from (select s.campaign_id campaign_id, s.scenario_index scenario_index 
            from scenario s, campaign c where s.campaign_id = c.campaign_id)
      pivot (max(scenario_index)for scenario_index in (1 as scenario1,2 as scenario2,3 as scenario3))
     )a
```